# What is wrong with these code in terms of aligning the script in Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: Website]This is just an example to understand why the script isn't aligned in the right way. Where is the wrong part?

**Here's the code:**

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <h3>Cloud Computable</h3>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-console" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <h3>GUI Free</h3>
            <p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <h3>Backwards Compatible</h3>
            <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? What's the right way? What currently happens? Give a [mcve], ideally as a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 0):

from the snippet of code that you provided nothing is really wrong. The snippet is doing exactly what you are telling the divs to do. the 'col' reference is to what you want the divs to do when the view is expanded or shrunk. Bootstrap uses a grid system [view here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to learn more about the Bootstrap 'col' usage.

Here is the snippet you provided, but with 'col-xs, col-md, and col-lg' support and it views fine and aligned when the view is shrunken or expanded. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jameswassinger/qozvjLty/)

Let me know if that helps.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 col-lg-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <h3>Cloud Computable</h3>
            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 col-lg-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-console" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <h3>GUI Free</h3>
            <p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 col-lg-4">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <h3>Backwards Compatible</h3>
            <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately. It remains the same.

Comment: Sorry, Perhaps if you provide the actual code that is giving you a problem I could better help.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I've changed the code so... I'll just try to play with some more elements and return to this detail after getting a grasp of more important basics.